# numpy - changes shape automatically?

Tags: python, numpy

I am a little bit confused by numpy.

```
train_images = load_images(X_train[:205])
print(train_images.shape)
train_images = load_images(X_train[:206])
print(train_images.shape)
```

results in:

```
(205, 12288)
(206,)
```

Is this a bug or how can I force numpy to keep the shape?

Here is my image load func:

```
def load_image(f):
    im = Image.open(path+f)
    result = np.array(list(im.getdata())).ravel()
    return result

def load_images(fs):
    result = list()
    for f in fs:
        result.append(load_image(f))
    return np.array(result)
```

EDIT: The answer is that all images have to be of the same size.. And exactly one image had another size..

Comment: [You can provide your own answer and accept it after 48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) This is better than to hide it in an `Edit`, people see immediately that an answer already exists.

Comment: FYI, you can just do `np.array(im)` for PIL images. You don't need to convert to a list or use the `.getdata()` method. So `np.array(im).ravel` should set you up fine.

Comment: Thanks for this hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that all images have to be of the same size.. And exactly one image had another size..